# Dapper is returning null when join is introduced to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have a peculiar issue that I cannot seem to find any answers on. It seems that when I introduce a join to a stored procedure, Dapper's mapping refuses to work properly.

My custom object:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string ColumnOne { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ColumnThree { get; set; }
    public string ColumnFour { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository call, the `customObjects` is always returning 0 results.

My repository call with Dapper:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomObject> GetTheThings(int? integerParameter)
{
    List<CustomObject> customObjects;

    using (var connection = "connection string syntax"))
    {
        string sql = "[storedProcedureName]";

        connection.Open();

        customObjects = connection.Query<CustomObject>(sql,
                new { IntegerParameter = integerParameter },
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }

    return customObjects;
}
```

Stored procedure's basic syntax:

```
SELECT  
    t1.column_one AS [ColumnOne],         -- column_one is nvarchar data type
    t2.column_two_thing AS [ColumnTwo],   -- column_two_thing is nvarchar data type
    t2.column_three AS [ColumnThree],     -- column_three is DateTime data type
    t2.column_four AS [ColumnFour]        -- column_four is nvarchar data type
FROM 
    Table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    Table2 t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON t1.Identifier = t2.Identifier -- Identifiers are both uniqueidentifier data types
WHERE 
    t1.column_one = @IntegerParameter;
```

When I execute this stored procedure directly in SSMS, it returns the values that I'm expecting and in the format I'm expecting

| ColumnOne | ColumnTwo | ColumnThree | ColumnFour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TextOne | ColumnTwoResultTextOne | 2021-12-16 00:00:00.001 | ColumnFourResultTextOne |
| TextOne | ColumnTwoResultTextTwo | 2021-12-16 00:00:00.001 | ColumnFourResultTextTwo |
| TextOne | ColumnTwoResultTextThree | 2021-12-16 00:00:00.001 | ColumnFourResultTextThree |
| TextOne | ColumnTwoResultTextFour | 2021-12-16 00:00:00.001 | ColumnFourResultTextFour |

When I execute via my application at runtime with Dapper, the results that return are 0.

For some reason, when I remove the join, and I manually type values for the columns that rely on the join, I receive results back.

Script that returns results and maps appropriately:

```
SELECT  
    t1.column_one AS [ColumnOne],         -- column_one is nvarchar data type
    'Literally anything' AS [ColumnTwo],  -- column_two_thing is nvarchar data type
    GETDATE() AS [ColumnThree],           -- column_three is DateTime data type
    'Anything here too' AS [ColumnFour]   -- column_four is nvarchar data type
FROM 
    Table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    t1.column_one = @IntegerParameter;
```

I've also tried replacing each column with a hard coded `'Literally anything' as [ColumnName]` to ensure it wasn't just a property being lost in Dapper translation, but no results would return from my method at runtime so long as the join was within the query.

I've been reading the Dapper documentation and perusing through StackOverflow and other resources for any suggestions, but cannot find where I have gone wrong.

Any and all help or suggestions would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for posting that. These records have an extraordinarily low chance for dirty reads so the freeing up of the threads is of higher importance.

Comment: If there is no chance of anyone else accessing the table, why don't you use `TABLOCK` or `SNAPSHOT`? And if you can't do that due to other clients accessing the table then you have dirty reads. And why do you think "freeing threads" is an issue you have?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing the *actual* table definitions and the *actual* query. I very much doubt Dapper has anything to do with this, it's almost certainly a join problem

Comment: The freeing up of what now? `NOLOCK` does absolutely nothing for threading. Notably, not taking read locks isn't going to somehow improve concurrent throughput if rows aren't being modified, while it's obviously a bad idea if they *are* being modified. The only time you should consider `NOLOCK` is if you can afford to not care about incorrect results (for example, because the query is executed periodically anyway), not because you're feeling good about the odds. If you have a scenario where you want to ensure readers and writers don't block each other, consider snapshot isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are getting no rows at all suggests that there are no results in your two tables which can be joined.

The JOIN statement will be an inner join by default. This will return only records that have matching values in both tables.

EDIT: In this case, the inconsistency between running the query in SSMS and Dapper was because of the permissions of the accounts in the connection string were not the same. Because of this the data in one of the tables could not be accessed, so the JOIN returned no rows.

Comment: When performing a LEFT JOIN, I receive a single result back that has ColumnOne and ColumnThree populated at runtime, but the other two are still empty.

When I run the LEFT JOIN in the database, it still returns multiple results with each column populated.

Comment: The fact that there is a difference would seem to confirm that there is no data which can be joined in the DB. I realise this is probably a daft suggestion - but are you sure that the code is talking to the same DB as your SSMS connection?

Comment: Yepyep, I just triple-checked to ensure it's the same server, same database, and connection strings were all set. It's a new stored procedure that I've written this morning and I'm running it locally to verify that it's hitting the correct spots.

Comment: Well, I've figured it out and I think your comments helped push me in the right direction. The problem I was running in to was that the accounts identified in the connection strings didn't have access to view the data within one of the joined tables. 

I actually ended up gutting Dapper and manually executing and mapping my objects so I could debug quite a bit more. Seeing that only one of the tables returned any data, I dug into the connection strings, logged in as the user, then executed the queries within the sproc.

Comment: I'm not a fan of answering my own questions, so if you'd like to add or edit your answers, I'd be more than happy to mark this one as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Well, I can't claim I answered your question :D I'll update the question for future users. Sometimes all it takes is to explain it to someone else.